# How to create a pagination photos?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'd like to integrate a pagination in photo gallery project.

Ex: << previous 1 2 3 next >>

Let's say I have 13 photos and want to display on each page first 6 photos. So in total, I must have 3 pages of 6 photos each and each page number is clickable to display the maximum of 6 photos...

How would I proceed the right method?

Here's what I though:

```
var totalPhotos:uint;
var maxNumberThumbPerPage:uint = 6;
var totalPage:uint;

totalPhotos = tabPhoto.length;
totalPage = Math.ceil(totalPhotos/maxNumberThumbPerPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a function that goes something like this

```
var imagesArray:Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];

function createPage($pageNum:int, $perPage:int = 6):Array{ // though vector is preferred
    // imagesArray - the array holdig all the images
    var iStart:int = $pageNum * $perPage;
    var iEnd:int = ($pageNum + 1) * $perPage;
    if (iEnd > imagesArray.length) { iEnd = imagesArray.length}
    return imagesArray.slice(iStart, iEnd);
}

trace( createPage(0));
trace( createPage(1));
trace( createPage(2));
```

this will get you the content of each page, this is one of the trickier parts, but as you can see still pretty simple.

other part would be to create the navigation and create the rendering part

Comment: I miss Ruby's range class sometimes when using AS3 http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html

Comment: Awesome! It looks so simple but trickier, I couldn't figured it out. and yes, I only use Vector instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How to create the navigation dynamically and rendering part?

Comment: hmm, this would be a pretty long description. You can try this class at http://tyleregeto.com/entries/single/id/paginator-as3  otherwise I'd suggest using an MVC design pattern, braking it up into separate parts and try to get help for each chunk separately. Posting a how to for the entire process is quite a bit of work so you might not have many people willing to go through all that.